# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_category" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I started a Django project and I am not sure what I am missing. Prior to this error, I deleted the database, and deleted the migrations as well because I wanted the post to have an UUID.

I got this error when I created my docker-compose-prod.yml file and all the django security stuff in the settings.py file(I am assuming all the security code I wrote in the settings.py file work because the warning signs do not show up):

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_category" does not exist
```

As of right now, I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Also, I do not want to delete the migrations or make any changes within the database because I have the "post data" and I remember I ran into this issue a long time ago, but decided to ignore it(Meaning I went with the delete the migrations).

**More detail version of the error**:

```
web_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_category" does not exist
web_1  | LINE 1: ...log_category"."name", "blog_category"."name" FROM "blog_cate...
...
web_1  |   File "/code/datablog_project/urls.py", line 30, in 
<module>
web_1  |     path('',include('blog.urls')),
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
...
web_1  |   File "/code/blog/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
web_1  |     from .views import (
web_1  |   File "/code/blog/views.py", line 25, in <module>
web_1  |     from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, CommentForm, 
EditCommentForm
web_1  |   File "/code/blog/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
web_1  |     for item in choices:
```

I checked my url, views, forms, and model. And I can't seem to spot the error.

url.py:

```
from .views import (
...
CategoryView,
CategoryListView,
...
)

urlpatterns = [
...
path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
path('category-list/',CategoryListView, name='category-list'),
...
]
```

views.py:

```
from .models import Post, Category, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, CommentForm, EditCommentForm

...
def CategoryView(request, cats):
   category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats.title().replace('-',' '))
   return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats': cats.title().replace('-',' '), 'category_posts': category_posts})

def CategoryListView(request):
   cat_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'blog/category_list.html', {'cat_menu_list': cat_menu_list})
...
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post,Category, Comment

choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', name')
choice_list = []

for item in choices:
   choice_list.append(item)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields =('title', 'category', 'body')

       widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list,attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

    }
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
 ...
 class Post(models.Model):
     id = models.UUIDField(
         primary_key = True,
         default = uuid.uuid4,
         editable = False)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     author = models.ForeignKey(
         get_user_model(),
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
     )
     body = RichTextField()
     category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Miscellaneous')
     ...
```

2nd migration in my blog app:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('blog', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Category',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='profile',
        name='linkedin_url',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='profile',
        name='website_url',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='post',
        name='category',
        field=models.CharField(default='Miscellaneous', max_length=255),
    ),
]
```

Comment: did you delete `django_migrations` table?

Comment: try running; python manage.py migrate --fake , if your models' schema matches the database tables' schema

Comment: @kochul, I am not too sure if I deleted the django_migrations table since I am fairly new to django. I just remember doing this -> "sudo docker-compose exec web rm -r blog/migrations" -> sudo docker volume ls -> "sudo docker volume rm djangoproject_postgres_data". From here, I reran the migrations again because I added an UUID.

Comment: @danish_wani, I can't seem to get that command working in ubuntu and docker. I still get the same error as before.

Comment: @SL42 actually I have the same error did you found a solution for this